# Python: фильтрация списков

Tags: python

Имеется список `list`

```
df = [
    {'A': 'er', 'B': 'po'},
    {'A': 'rf', 'B': 'pl'},
    {'A': 'ed', 'B': 'fd'}
]
```

Просьба, подсказать, как можно фильтровать подобный список без использования `pandas`, при условии что фильтр может примениться как к `А` так и `В` или же к обоим сразу, на входные данные список `list` для примера где `А = ['er', 'ed']`,
Пробовал собирать функцию с перебором `for` и проверкой `if .. in:` в случае где применяется к одному из `2ух` ключей фильтрация работает корректно, но при фильтрации по 2ум одновременно ключам результат получается не совсем корректный

мои попытки:

```
A = ['er', 'ed']
B = []
def filter(A, B):
    result = []
    if not A:
        for fl in A:
            for row in df:
                if fl in['A']:
                    result.append(row)
    else:
        result.append(df)
    return result
```

для единичного, с добавлением фильтрации еще по одному ключу возникает сложности

Comment: И как пробовали? Приведите ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_filter(one_argument):
   if one_argument['A'] or one_argument['B']:
     return False
   return True

filter(my_filter,[
    {'A': 'er', 'B': 'po'},
    {'A': 'rf', 'B': 'pl'},
    {'A': 'ed', 'B': 'fd'}
])
```

функция filter фильтрует список используя пользовательскую функцию my_filter
функция my_filter принимает один элемент из списка, в твоём случае этот элемент словарь, следовательно имеет доступ по ключам

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение для двух условий:

```
df = [
    {'A': 'er', 'B': 'po'},
    {'A': 'rf', 'B': 'pl'},
    {'A': 'ed', 'B': 'fd'}
]

A = ['er', 'rf']
B = ['po', 'fd']

res = [elem for elem in df if (elem['A'] in A and elem['B'] in B) or
   (elem['A'] in A and not B) or (elem['B'] in B and not A)]
print(res)
```

Comment: понравилось Ваше решение, как быть в случае если на входящие данные был подан пустой список? т.е. B = ['po', 'fd'] и А = [], сейчас он возвращает пустой список []

Comment: Спасибо за замечание! Сейчас решение полное.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде универсальный oneliner получился. Может фильтровать по любому количеству ключей.

```
df = [
    {'A': 'er', 'B': 'po'},
    {'A': 'rf', 'B': 'pl'},
    {'A': 'ed', 'B': 'fd'}
]

flt = {'A': ['er', 'ed'],
       'B': ['fd']}
res = [d for d in df if all(d[k] in v for k,v in flt.items())]
print(res)

flt = {'A': ['er', 'ed']}
res = [d for d in df if all(d[k] in v for k,v in flt.items())]
print(res)

flt = {'B': ['po', 'pl']}
res = [d for d in df if all(d[k] in v for k,v in flt.items())]
print(res)
```

```
[{'A': 'ed', 'B': 'fd'}]
[{'A': 'er', 'B': 'po'}, {'A': 'ed', 'B': 'fd'}]
[{'A': 'er', 'B': 'po'}, {'A': 'rf', 'B': 'pl'}]
```

Это по `И`. Если надо по `ИЛИ`, то использовать `any` вместо `all`.